# Disable Swipe in Carousel Page, Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a use case where I need to disable swiping on Carousel Page. I will always have 3 or more pages in my carousel and want to set the CurrentPage through code behind only. I have tried using InputTransparent = true on the CarouselPage and on the individual Content Pages to no avail.

I dont mind using TabbedPage but but the problem with that is, I only want to have 3 specific Tab header Buttons even if I have 3+ number of pages in the TabbedPage. So I would need a way to hide Tabbar Btns dynamically.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Please I can help you but first show me some code of your work already

Comment: This is more of a concept question so I cant really show you any specific piece of code for this.

Comment: I can give you some idea, you can create a custom carousel page renderer and remove the gesture recognizer or remove all the pages and leave only the initial page to only preview the initial data.

Comment: I found this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72031/is-there-a-way-to-disable-swipe-gesture-when-using-carouselpage